# Loading SVG with IMG and recalling it with XHR to use it inline

Tags: javascript, html, svg, dom

If we load an `SVG` file within `IMG` tag and request the same file with `XHR` after "`onload`" event. Does this result in requesting the same file twice?

Or does the file come from **disk or memory cache**? Or does it make a request from the server and return with the `304 status code`?

So I tested it, but there are differences between "`localhost::`" and the normal server. Moreover, there seem to be differences between browsers as well.

> In some cases Mozilla seems to have a much better caching policy.

The interesting part is that I request the same file with `XHR` after the "`onload`" event and replace the `IMG` tag with the `SVG element` so that I can take advantage of **inline** `SVG` features.

However, waiting for **(IMG)** to load is okay, but I can't tolerate a 2nd load time. How stable do you think this technology is? I mean, I couldn't do a quality test. Do you think the file will be inject directly from the cache in a few ms?

Comment: Why load it with the IMG tag at all in the first place if you're going to replace it anyway?

Comment: @AKX In this way, you can ensure that the file is "Client Side" cached. The cache is very important in a large <SYMBOL> set.

Comment: The cleaner way to achieve this would be with a [`<link rel="preload">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content).